# Why doesn't Heroku accept empty folders?

Tags: git, heroku

Hi I am currently trying to deploy an app on Heroku (well actually I did it 2 years ago but only recently I noticed this bug), and I have a folder structure like this: `/work/{{id.name}}/{{id.tag}}` and since tags limited to three currently the folders are pre-generated before deploy and they are empty. The problem with Heroku (and it works on AWS or IBM Bluemix) is that it does not seem to allow the unload of empty folders (at least not completely). I have some folders existing, like `/work/alina/outdoor/` but some disappeared like `/work/james/indoor`...

I like to know if this is a Heroku bug or a Git bug, or perhaps it isn't really a bug just something I did wrong when deploying or pushing to Heroku's git repo...thanks.

Comment: It is not a Git bug but works as design. Empty directories cannot be tracked by Git. At least one file is needed but Git does not care what the file is. https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F

Comment: @ElpieKay oh no...so I guess I need to modify my code. Is there a quick hack to work around this or turn the tracking on for git somehow? :)

Comment: In practice we usually put an empty file like `.gitignore`, `.gitattribute` or `readme` in the empty folder. They are not essential and have no negative side-effects on the repository or the code. But they can come into use when needed.

Comment: @ElpieKay adding new files means rewriting the code...

Answer (score 8):

This is not an Heroku restriction. It's a GIT one. It won't track folders with no files inside them.

The solution to this is to create a hidden file inside that folder, so it looks empty but truly isn't. The convention is usually to name that file `.gitkeep`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but to make it more elaborate heroku also omits the empty folders and so any file in the empty folder will do the magic it does not have to be strictly .gitkeep any way you mentioned that its only a convention/good practice.